# Данные из бд с пагинацией и без - одно и тоже?

Tags: c#, sql, pagination, stored-procedures

У меня есть интерфейс IRepository и я подумал было бы хорошо если бы сделать метод `getAll` и метод `GetAllWithPaging` одним но как это сделать если `getAll` вытаскивает всю инфу из бд а `GetAllWithPaging` только заданное кол-во

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    int Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Edit(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllWithPaging(int PageNumber);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
}
```

Вот хронимка пагинации sql

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetAllProjectsPaging]
(
    @PageNumber int,
    @RecordsPerPage int
)   
as    
Begin    
    Select * From TrainingTask.dbo.Project
    ORDER BY Id
    OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RecordsPerPage) ROWS FETCH NEXT @RecordsPerPage ROWS ONLY
End
```

Comment: Если делаете пейджинг, то 1) при запросе страницы отправляйте не только номер страницы, но и количество записей на станицу (размер страницы) 2) При получении результата на клиент отправляйтене только данные, но и номер страницы, размер страницы, общее количество записей.

Comment: окей и как помимо данных которые мне надо получить общее кол-во?

Comment: То есть вы хотите внутри `GetAllWithPaging` использовать `GetAll`? Т. к. последняя возвращает `IEnumerable`, то это невозможно (вернее, неэффективно). Либо реализуйте `GetAllWithPaging` отдельно, саму по себе, либо пусть `GetAll` возвращает `IQueryable`.

Comment: окей у меня getall будет возвраать IQueryable и что дальше?

Comment: `мне надо получить общее кол-во` либо надо будет такой запрос написать, чтобы вернул 2 датасета, либо получить общее колво отдельным запросом.

Comment: и как же вернуть 2 датасета?

Comment: у меня уже есть общее ко-во отдельным запросом это getAll